# $A\sin\alpha + B\cos\alpha = C\sin\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

I was just reading a trigonometric functions page when this equation suddenly popped into my mind. It is as follows:
$A\sin\alpha + B\cos\alpha = C\sin\alpha$

I feel like $A$ should equal $C$ by equating coefficients and $B$ should equal $0$, but I'm having an extremely hard time trying to figure out why it is true/untrue. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: If $\alpha=\pi/4$ then you can choose $A=B=1, C=2$

Comment: not necessarily, you have to move $C sin \alpha $ to LHS sum it with $A sin \alpha$ and solve equation $(A+c)sin \alpha=-B cos \alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying $A\sin\alpha + B\cos\alpha = C\sin\alpha$ you can rewrite as $$A\sin\alpha + B\cos\alpha -C\sin\alpha=0\\(A-C)\sin\alpha + B\cos\alpha=0 \to \div \cos\alpha\\(A-C)\tan \alpha =-B \\\tan \alpha =-\frac{B}{A-C}$$ but if you are trying
$A\sin\alpha + B\cos\alpha = C$  you can use the fact $$A\sin\alpha + B\cos\alpha = \frac{A}{|A|}\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(x+\arctan \frac{B}{A})=c$$it can turn the equation to $$\sin(x+\arctan \frac{B}{A})=k$$

Comment: Just what I was thinking, @Khosrotash.. but you could express $\cos\alpha$ in terms of $\sin\alpha$ as $\frac{\sin\alpha}{\tan\alpha}$, right ?

Comment: @Spectre: sure, but is it helps to solve this equation  ?

Comment: Maybe, but I believe that you'll get what $\sin\alpha$ and all other trig ratios are (if $A,B,C$ are known).

Comment: You can't get $\alpha$ using my method unless you know how to take $\tan^{-1}\alpha$ (or $\arctan\alpha$).

Answer (score 1):

If $\sin\alpha=0$, the equation

$$A\sin\alpha+B\cos\alpha=C\sin\alpha\tag{1}$$

becomes $B\cos\alpha=0$, and since $\cos\alpha\ne 0$ when $\sin\alpha=0$, this is true if and only if $B=0$; $A$ and $C$ can be anything. If $\sin\alpha\ne 0$, divide $(1)$ through by $\sin\alpha$ to get

$$A+B\cot\alpha=C\,;$$

in this case $C$ is uniquely determined by $A,B$, and $\alpha$, and it is equal to $A$ if and only if either $B=0$, or $\cot\alpha=0$. And $\cot\alpha=0$ if and only if $\cos\alpha=0$, i.e., if and only if $\alpha=\frac{\pi}2+n\pi$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$.